ruby: multithreading in a docker container does not work
I tested ractors in ruby with docker and without
this is my script
ractors = []
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("Single thread:") do
    cpu_intensive_task
    cpu_intensive_task
  end

   x.report("Two ractors:") do
     2.times do
       ractors << Ractor.new { cpu_intensive_task }
     end
     ractors.each(&:take)
   end
end


when I run it local I see
       user     system      total        real
Single thread:  0.938003   0.000150   0.938153 (  0.942506)
Two ractors:  1.177639   0.000387   1.178026 (  0.592312)

but when I run it docker container I see
       user     system      total        real
Single thread:  1.221073   0.000000   1.221073 (  1.221220)
Two ractors:  2.448438   0.000995   2.449433 (  1.314552)

how to see real multithreading in docker?
I tried to configure my container with command like a
docker run --rm -it -v `pwd`:/app --memory="1g" --memory-swap="1g" --cpus="4" --ipc='shareable' ruby bash

but nothing helps.

C Ruby (MRI) has a global interpreter lock (GIL) which ensures that only a single thread runs at a time. This is still useful to parallelize e.g. IO operations but won't save you with CPU bound operations. If you need true parallel execution without a GIL, you have to use a different Ruby implementation such as JRuby.

this is true for threads, but not for ractors. we see that ractors run twice as fast locally, but are slower in docker

Your title is a bit misleading as the code obviously does "work". Just because you called the method in the post "cpu_intensive_task" does not actually identify anything. If that task also happens to be even slightly memory intensive (1g is not a lot) as well then the memory usage could in theory cause bottle necking. If you only have 1GB of RAM to use and both Ractors are trying to share it (without swap based on your options) there is going to be some fighting over resources that  the single threaded application will not experience.

with 4 gb I see the same result
